# mvvm light -Sending Notification message with callback

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I need the result of FolderBrowserDialog in my view-model,

CodeBehind.cs

```
 private static void SelectFolderDialog()
    {
        using (System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderdialg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            folderdialg.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
            folderdialg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;

            folderdialg.Description = "Load Images for the Game";
            folderdialg.ShowDialog();
            if (folderdialg.SelectedPath != null)
            {
                var notifypath = new GenericMessage<string>(folderdialg.SelectedPath);
                Messenger.Default.Send(notifypath);

            }
        }
```

What i'm planning  is , From View-model send a notification with callback to view , executing the FolderBrowserDialog return the Selected path back to the view model.

How do i send notificationmessage with callback / NotificationWithAction using MVVM-Light . please help me with a sample as I'm new to Wpf and MVVM-Light.

Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for almost the exact same thing except for with a `SaveFileDialog`. Here is what I came up with:

Create a message class with an `Action<string>` property and a constructor with an `Action<string>` argument.

```
public class SelectFolderMessage
{
    public Action<string> CallBack {get;set;}
    public SelectFolderMessage(Action<string> callback)
    {
         CallBack = callback;
    }
}
```

In your ViewModel class, pass in a method or lambda expression when you call `Messenger.Default.Send`. I set a property in my ViewModel class with the path returned by the view. I wrapped this inside the execute section of a `RelayCommand`. I bound the `RelayCommand` to a button in the view

```
...
new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new SelectFolderMessage(
            (pathfromview) => { viewmodelproperty = pathfromview;}));
    })
```

In your view code behind, create a method to handle the message and register the handler with the messenger service. Don't forget to unregister if this is not your main window.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<SelectFolderMessage>(this, SelectFolderHandler);
}

private void SelectFolderHandler(SelectFolderMessage msg)
{
    using (System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderdialg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        folderdialg.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        folderdialg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;

        folderdialg.Description = "Load Images for the Game";
        folderdialg.ShowDialog();
        if (folderdialg.SelectedPath != null)
        {
            msg.CallBack(folderdialg.SelectedPath);
        }
    }
}
```

I came up with this idea reading Laurent Bugnion's Messenger article in MSDN Magazine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx

Comment: **its a better solution . Thank you**,   How could i manage this if its Interface driven, I was considering unit-test ability also.

Comment: Check out the "Implementing a DialogService" part of the article in the link above. Laurent shows an example of using an interface and unit testing.

Comment: Update 2017: Meanwhile there are (in MVVMlight.Messaging) `NotificationMessageAction`, `NotificationMessageAction<>`, and `NotificationMessageWithCallback`.